# Magento how to show product attribute in product page?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I am using a attribute to show a attribute value in product page code is:

```
getProductShipping()):?>
Shipping Charges : Rs.getProductShipping(); ?>
```

it is showing Shipping Charges : Rs. 20 what is the value of attribute. if some products has no value in this product then nothing is showing there but i want to show Free shipping if no value is there. i want the code please help me.

attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work like this way:

```
<?php if($product->getProductShipping()) { ?>
   Shipping Charges : Rs. <?php echo $product->getProductShipping(); ?>
<?php } else { ?>   
   Free Shipping
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: getProductShipping is working fine for you ? you are facing issue in showing Free Shipping when it is empty .. right ?